# how to join 2 collection in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

i have 2 collection

material_pack

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5e43bd417b5590b641d2f408"),
  "title" : "untitle",
  "ref" : [ 
    {"id" : ObjectId("5e43bd517b5590b641d2f409")},
    {"id" : ObjectId("5e43bd517b5590b641d2f40a")},
    {"id" : ObjectId("5e43bd517b5590b641d2f40b")}
]
```

and 
material

```
[
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e43bd517b5590b641d2f409"),
    "mine_type" : "image/gif"
  },
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e43bd517b5590b641d2f40a"),
    "mine_type" : "image/jpeg"
  },
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e43bd517b5590b641d2f40b"),
    "mine_type" : "image/jpeg"
  },
]
```

and what i want is joint them with this code

```
db.material_pack.aggregate([
   {
     $lookup:
       {
         from: 'material',
         localField: 'ref.id',
         foreignField: '_id',
         as: "items_document"
       }
  }
])
```

but result of items_document field is [ ]

my result :

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5e43bd417b5590b641d2f408"),
  "title" : "untitle",
  "content" : "",
  "categories" : [],
  "ref" : [ 
    {
        "id" : ObjectId("5e43bd517b5590b641d2f409")
    }, 
    {
        "id" : ObjectId("5e43bd517b5590b641d2f40a")
    }, 
    {
        "id" : ObjectId("5e43bd517b5590b641d2f40b")
    }
  ],
  "items_document" : [ ]
 }
```

i want result like this :

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5e43bd417b5590b641d2f408"),
  "title" : "untitle",
  "content" : "",
  "categories" : [],
  "ref" : [ 
    {
        "id" : ObjectId("5e43bd517b5590b641d2f409")
    }, 
    {
        "id" : ObjectId("5e43bd517b5590b641d2f40a")
    }, 
    {
        "id" : ObjectId("5e43bd517b5590b641d2f40b")
    }
  ],
  "items_document" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5e43bd517b5590b641d2f409"),
        "mine_type" : "image/gif",
        ...
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5e43bd517b5590b641d2f40a"),
        "mine_type" : "image/jpeg",
        ...
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5e43bd517b5590b641d2f40b"),
        "mine_type" : "image/jpeg",
        ...
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I have tried your code. It is working perfectly fine. May be double check the collection name and field names in your code.

Comment: I've also just tried running the query and I get the correct results.

Comment: thank you for answer it look like my code is correct but somehow it not working in that db, so i solve this problem by change db and it work now
but i don't understand why this problem happened ?

Answer (score -1):

Hello Apiwut Trusphimai,
Please check this [Mongo Play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/De8wQoiRNt6), It may help you.
I've used your code and collections and there are no any changes required in your code its works well you can check in my given link.